# How to return error responses from Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvp

I'm trying to change all my callbacks to coroutines, I have readed about them and they are fasinating !

What I want to accomplish is just login a user, but if the login logic fails, notify it to my presenter.

This is what I have made

### LoginPresenter.kt

```
class LoginPresenter @Inject constructor(private val signInInteractor: SignInInteractor) : LoginContract.Presenter, CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = job + Dispatchers.Main

override fun signInWithCoroutines(email: String, password: String) {

        launch {
            view?.showProgress()
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
                signInInteractor.signInWithCoroutinesTest(email,password)
            }
            view?.hideProgress()
        }

    }
}
```

And now the problem is in my interactor, since its a suspend function, I would love to return an error response in order to do a `view.showError(errorMsg)` from my presenter

### SignInInteractor.kt

```
 override suspend fun signInWithCoroutinesTest(email: String, password: String) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()?.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { 
            if(it.isSuccessful){
                //Want to notify the presenter that the coroutine has ended succefully
            }else{
                //want to let the courutine know about it.exception.message.tostring
            }
        }

    }
```

The way I was doing it was with callbacks that notify my presenter

```
 override fun signInWithCoroutinesTest(email: String, password: String) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()?.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password,listener:OnSuccessCallback).addOnCompleteListener { 
            if(it.isSuccessful){
                listener.onSuccess()
            }else{
                listener.onFailure(it.exception.message.toString())
            }
        }


    }
```

### Question

How to return if the operation has succeded from coroutines and notify my presenter?

Thanks

Comment: I think you can use normal try catch.
`
launch {
            try {
                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).await()
                
                startMainActivity()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                showError(e.localizedMessage)
            }
        }
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must explicitly suspend the coroutine:

```
override suspend fun signInWithCoroutinesTest(
         email: String, password: String
) = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance()?.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { 
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                continuation.resume(Unit)
            } else {
                continuation.resumeWithException(it.exception)
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, since your code is suspendable and not blocking, don't run it `withContext(IO)`. Simply call it directly from the main thread, that's the beauty of coroutines.

Comment: Hey Marko, thanks so much for taking the time to answer, I have 2 questions, first, how do I retrieve the continuation exception and resume withing the presenter after I call **signInInteractor.signInWithCoroutinesTest(email,password)**  , and by deleting the withContext(io) you mean just calling from my view, **presenter.signInWithCoroutines()** and nothing more ? Thanks

Comment: 1. You catch the exception that `signInWithCoroutinesTest` throws. 2. Yes, unwrap the `withContext(IO) {}` block.

Comment: I'm just explaining how one goes about "retrieving the continuation exception", not giving architectural advice. Design your code to catch the exception in the most appropriate place.

Comment: yes, I mean, from my presenter, can I retrieve the continuation.resume without doing a try catch ?, thats the only thing that I need to completly understand it

Comment: The call of `signInWithCoroutine` completes when the continuation resumes. Then the rest of your presenter code runs.

Answer (score 1):

Think of coroutines as you would normal, synchronous code. How would you write this if the background work completed immediately? Maybe something like this:

```
override fun signInWithCoroutinesTest(email: String, password: String) {
    view?.showProgress()
    if(!signInInteractor.signIn(email,password)) view?.showSignInError()
    view?.hideProgress()
}
```

Or if you want to catch the error, something like this

```
override fun signInWithCoroutinesTest(email: String, password: String) {
    view?.showProgress()
    try {
        signInInteractor.signIn(email,password))
    } catch(e: AuthenticationException) {
        view?.showError(e.message)
    }
    view?.hideProgress()
}
```

With coroutines, you just write the exact same code but the methods themselves suspend rather than block threads. So in this case `signIn` would be a suspending function and will need to be called from a coroutine or other suspend function. Based on that, you probably want the outer function to suspend and then you would launch *that* coroutine rather than trying to launch inside of `signInWithCoroutinesTest`.

The original example isn't completely realistic but normally you would launch this kind of thing from an existing scope, perhaps associated with your activity or viewModel. Ultimately, it would look something like this:

```
fun hypotheticalLogic() {
   ...
   viewModelScope.launch {
       signInWithCoroutinesTest(email, password)
   }
   ...
}

override suspend fun signInWithCoroutinesTest(email: String, password: String) {
    view?.showProgress()
    try {
        signInInteractor.signIn(email,password))
    } catch(e: AuthenticationException) {
        view?.showError(e.message)
    }
    view?.hideProgress()
}
```

The key point is just to think of coroutines the same as you would "normal" sequential code.